# Will Airflow dag level retries value override task level retries value?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I noticed a no-host error combined with no log found in task folder. My tasks have retries set to 3. Also, the dag has retries set to 1. Does the retry value set at dag level overrides task retry? I noticed it didn't retry after that failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a DAG level `retries`.
You are probably confused by `default_args` which may contains `retries` and passed to the DAG contractor as:

```
default_args = {
    'retries': 4
}
with DAG(
        dag_id='my_dag',
        default_args=default_args,
        ...
) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date',
    )
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='sleep',
        bash_command='sleep 5',
        retries=3,
    )
```

The `default_args` is a dictionary passed to the **tasks** it serves as a way to set defaults values to all tasks in the DAG.
In the above example `t1` will have 4 retries because it's the default from `default_args` but `t2` will have 3 retries because it overwrites the default.

Comment: Thank you @Elad! You're right. I did get confused by default_args. After re-checking the task log, it indeed re-tried 3 times and failed to get resources from spark.